# UITableView Not displaying data AND not adding data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I was watching this Youtube tutorial on how to dynamically add cells to a UITableView in Swift.

I followed the video down to a tee but author neglected to show his UITableView Custom cell file, so I believe that that is where my issue is.

Again my issue is my data in my array foods is not showing, and I am unable to add data to my array.

Here is my viewController class -

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var addFoodtextField: UITextField!

var foods: [String] = ["Bananas", "eggs", "grapes"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
}

@IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    insertNewFoodTitle()
}

func insertNewFoodTitle() {
    foods.append(addFoodtextField.text!)

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: foods.count - 1, section: 0)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()

    addFoodtextField.text = ""
    view.endEditing(true)
}

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return foods.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let foodTitle = foods[indexPath.row]

        let cell =  self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foodCell") as! foodCell!
        cell?.foodTitle?.text = foodTitle

        return cell!
    }
}
```

And here is my foodCell class

```
import UIKit

class foodCell: UITableViewCell {

var foodTitle : UILabel?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

This is my app in the interface builder 
[image]

and this is what I see when my app runs
[image]

Comment: One simple thing to check, is put a breakpoint in your tableView delegate methods to make sure they're actually getting called.  If not, then you need to assign the table delegate and datasource in your xib/storyboard.

Comment: What are you seeing when the app runs?

Comment: This was not a very good tutorial you watched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing two lines in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self   // This class is the tableview's data source
    tableView.delegate = self   // This class is the tableview's delegate
}
```

Comment: when I added that my program crashed and it is saying my cell = nil...why is that?

Comment: This can also be done graphically in the xib file, so technically not required to be written via code in viewDidLoad.

Comment: For the nil crash, you need to assign that identifier to your custom cell in the xib file or else the dequeue doesn't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Cameron Right, and don't force unwrap your cell, it should be "foodcell", not "foodCell!" ... And it should really be FoodCell (capitalized) because it's a class name

Comment: @conarch thanks for the help! adding the dataSource and the delegate AND adding the cell identifier in the xib file make it work!

Comment: @Shades  thanks for the help! adding the dataSource and the delegate AND adding the cell identifier in the xib file make it work!